# how to make an http call to an api by sending along a .pfx file in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ssl, httprequest, httpclient

I'm performing an integration with a Bank api that needs this file to be sent. In postman I configure the certificate and password and I get the connection correctly. However, in my Angular project I am not finding the correct way to send this certificate (.pfx) along with my header.

What is the solution to be able to make this call to the API with the .pfx certificate?

```
const httpHeaders = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        })
    };

    const map = {
        'x-api-clientid': config.clienteId,
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
    }

    try {
        return await this.httpClient.post(config.url_token, map, httpHeaders).toPromise().then((resp: any) => {
            console.log('resp')
            console.log(resp)
            return resp
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('erro in post')
        console.log(error);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue. have you had any luck Wiharlley?

Comment: Hello. It is not possible to attach a certificate in the Angular layer. This certificate needs to be attached at a server layer or via an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to attach a certificate in the Angular layer. This certificate needs to be attached at a server layer or via an API. In my case, I implemented an API using Azure.